# sort merged object values in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have three object values to merge like

```
$videos = $this->Blogmodel>all_video_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);
$texts = $this->Blogmodel->all_text_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);
$audio = $this->Blogmodel->all_audio_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);

$data['array'] = array_merge($videos, $texts, $audio);
```

But the problem was values are sorted by one by one .. How to sort by date while merging ??

Comment: How are we supposed to know what the contents of your arrays are? You need to show more code. Also, you don't show any attempt to sort. What are you doing besides nothing?

Comment: Am getting text_interviews and video interviews and audio interviews by perticular one category . Three of them are in different table . so i take indiduvally the i merged .. It shows all videos interviews first then text interviews then audio interviews . But i need to sort by uploaded date .. i have a column name called posted_date at both three table .. How to do that

Comment: Show your array contents @GopinathParthee

Comment: text: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [text_id] => 1 [text_cat_id] => 1 [text_title] => Sample [text_description] =>

Sample Text
[interview_type] => 3 [posted_at] => 2017-12-08 13:10:59 ) )

Comment: video: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [video_id] => 7 [video_cat_id] => 3 [video_title] => sdgsghfr [video_description] =>

esyhhttrsgxfgbdzbhfz
[youtube_id] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kduLmg9CXl8 [interview_type] => 2 [posted_at] => 2017-11-29 15:50:00 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first merge the arrays and then sort the final array. 
You are probably looking for a multi-sort function. See below code:

```
$data = array_qsort2($data['array'], 'posted_date', "ASC");

function array_qsort2 (&$array, $column=0, $order="ASC") {
    $oper = ($order == "ASC")?">":"<";
    if(!is_array($array)) return;
    usort($array, create_function('$a,$b',"return (\$a['$column'] $oper \$b['$column']);")); 
    return ($array);
}
```